# How do I enable Search for Hindi content in mutilingual site in drupal?

Tags: drupal-6

I have created my site in Hindi as well as in English through i18n module of drupal. My search for English is working successfully, but if I search with respect to Hindi there are no search results.

How do I enable the ability to search of Hindi content?